# How to tell if an element of a quotient ring is a zero divisor

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am looking at Hartshorne Example III.9.8.4., p260.  He says that $a$ is not a zero divisor in $k[a,x,y,z]/I$, where $$
I = (a^2(x+1) -z^2, ax(x+1)-yz, xz-ay,y^2-x^2(x+1)). 
$$
Is there a good way to see this?

Comment: Perhaps one way would be to show that $a$ is not contained in a minimal prime, since the set of zero divisors is a union of minimal primes

Comment: Not very elegant or insightful, but you could compute $J := (a) \cap I$ and then show that $a^{-1}J = I$. Both the intersection and the equality check can be computed using [Groebner bases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gröbner_basis).

Comment: @Bruno -- The set of zero divisors is the union of the associated primes, and the set of associated primes is the set of minimal primes if the ring is reduced, I think.  Is it clear that this quotient is reduced?

Comment: @m_l -- What do you mean by $a^{-1}J$?  Are you computing this in the localization at $a$?

Comment: @paragon: No. This was sloppy notation, justified by the fact that $J \subset (a)$. Equivalently, you can show $J = aI$.

Comment: $a$ is a zero-divisor iff $af \in I$ for some $f \notin I$. We can assume $a$ does not divide $f$. I haven't done the calculations, but I'd assume some degree considerations would show that this is not possible.

Comment: @Fredrik: Why can we assume that? In $k[x]/x^2$, $x$ is a zero divisor, but $xf \in (x^2)$ implies $x$ divides $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me replace $a$ with $w.$ First, consider the domain $S = k[x,y]/(y^2-x^2(x+1)).$ Then $S[z,w]$ is a graded ring ($\mathbb N$-grading) generated in degree $1$ over $S$ by $\{z,w\}.$ Now $w^2(x+1)-z^2,wx(x+1)-yz,xz-wy$ are homogeneous elements of $S[z,w]$ of respective degrees $2,1,1.$ Thus the ideal generated by these elements is homogeneous, and the quotient $R = S[z,w]/(w^2(x+1)-z^2,wx(x+1)-yz,xz-wy)$ is graded. In particular, both $z,w$ still have degree $1$ in the quotient ($x,y$ are in degree $0$) <s>and so cannot possibly be zerodivisors, since their products with any nontrivial elements must have degree at least $1.$</s> But $R = k[x,y,z,w]/(w^2(x+1)-z^2,wx(x+1)-yz,xz-wy,y^2-x^2(x+1))$ is exactly our original ring, so we are done.

**Edit:**

This argument about degrees isn't very convincing.  How about the following:

The quotient ring $S = k[x,y,z] / \langle y^2 - x^2(x+1) \rangle$ is a domain, so injects into its quotient field $Q(S)$.  This yields an injection $S[a] \hookrightarrow Q(S)[a]$.  Now let $J \subset S[a]$ be defined by the three remaining relations.  Over $Q(S)[a]$, these all reduce to $a = xz/y$, so $Q(S)[a] / JQ(S)[a] = Q(S)$.  Thus there is a canonical map $S[a]/J \to Q(S)$ such that $a \mapsto xz/y$.  It is clear that if $a$ is a zero-divisor, then this map must send $a$ to $0$, which is false.  Hence $a$ cannot be a zero-divisor.

Comment: Could you explain further why, e.g., $w$ can't be a zerodivisor? I don't understand the relevance of the degree being $1$.

Comment: Dear @rj7k8, I think the original argument is flawed.  I've proposed another one.  Cheers

Comment: Thanks for returning to such an old question.